# What is the max size of Django cache and is there any chance to extend that?

Tags: django, caching, redis

I'm working on a project where i have to deal with big data (big number of rows)
To make the app fast I'm using redis with Django cache , I'm selecting all the data from Table A and saving it to cache as a json array, and later I select, update and delete from cache, I also have other tables B, c, D ... etc
Each table could hold more then 3 million rows in the future, probably more and more ...

I was wounding if Django cache can handle that?

If not what's the maximum size or rows that Django cache can store?

Is there a way to extend that, if not what are the order solutions for this problem?

I don't want to select data always from database, Because speed does matters here

Comment: Eventually, your cache will work as another database if you increase the cache, and this thus means that the cache will eventually be as slow as the database.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I agree but still selecting 2 million rows from cache is faster than selecting it from database at the end right?
any possible solutions? or answers to all the questions?

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on your RAM strength. You have no limits in Redis. datasize is limited to the amount of RAM you've allowed Redis to use.
don`t worry ,3 milions or more is an small data!
but if you have very big data you can try one of the following approach:

- Store the actual content/data on disk and store the index of data in
  redis. You can use [secondary indexes](https://redis.io/docs/manual/patterns/indexes/) by redis.
- Encode/Compress your data using any loss-less compression technique
  and then store in redis. Redis will not compress data for you.

Comment: How do I calculate how much i need for ram for like 2 or 3 millions rows in database?

Comment: read this https://success.outsystems.com/Documentation/How-to_Guides/Infrastructure/Configuring_OutSystems_with_Redis_in-memory_session_storage/System_requirements_for_using_Redis